# Where do messages go when using pythoncom.PumpMessages()?

Tags: python

I would like to know where does the function `pythoncom.PumpMessage()` stores the message when it comes into play. I was going through a site and just saw a Python Script for Key logger, I copied the code and used it on my computer but I don't feel safe, after deleting that code I think it's still running in the background and copying my keypresses. Is it so, please help.

Answer (score 2):

If the python script was sending messages to anyone, you'd probably be able to tell by looking at the code. Somewhere there would be a block of code sending some file to a server.

As for `PumpMessages()`, it

> Pumps all messages for the current thread until a WM_QUIT message.

According to [this](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/pythoncom__PumpMessages_meth.html) documentation. You can find other answered questions on this with a Google search as well. Pythoncom *isn't* sending any information to an external source in and of itself, however *your script* might be. You'd have to check your code for a block doing that.

As for it running after you delete the script, highly unlikely. If you didn't manually or programmatically (in the script) attach the Python script to some daemon, it isn't manifesting itself anywhere. You may be over-estimating the power of a basic Python keylogger. I wouldn't worry.

I've tried keyloggers before with pythoncom, and I've never had a problem. You can also look in the pythoncom library to find the `PumpMessages()` function and see if that is sending anything.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. I know you don't have the rep to comment, but answer section should be only for full answers. You asking for calcification isn't part of a full answer.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Can I remove it?

Comment: You can either delete it, or edit your "answer" to be a fulll answer, either one is up to you.

Comment: I can't figure out how to delete the answer on the mobile app.

Comment: I will keep it in mind next time I answer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Good update.  I was the down-voter.  I'm glad I checked back here.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it is of some use.